# Unable to access properties of an object within an array

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, parse-platform

I currently have an array of objects called results stored in a Parse database. I've been trying to access the properties of each of the objects in the results array.

I have a for loop that goes through each element of the results array, and another for loop inside that to go through and retrieve a specific property from each of the objects. In this case, the property is maxPrice, and I'm trying to retrieve the integer thats stored in the database. When I run this For loop, it returns a long list, as can be seen at the bottom instead of the number I'm looking for.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)     
{
     var stuff;
     var object = results[i];
     for (var maxPrice in object) //max price is the property
     {
          stuff = object[maxPrice];
          console.log(maxPrice, stuff);
      }
  }
```

Logs:

```
    I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _serverData
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _opSetQueue
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] attributes
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _hashedJSON
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _escapedAttributes
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] cid
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] changed
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _silent
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _pending
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _hasData
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _previousAttributes
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] id
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] createdAt
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] updatedAt
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] className
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] constructor
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] on
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] off
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] trigger
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] bind
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] unbind
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _existed
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] initialize
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] toJSON
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _toFullJSON
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _refreshCache
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] dirty
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] dirtyKeys
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _toPointer
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] get
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] relation
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] escape
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] has
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _mergeMagicFields
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _copyServerData
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _mergeFromObject
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.589Z] _startSave
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _cancelSave
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _finishSave
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _finishFetch
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _applyOpSet
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _resetCacheForKey
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _rebuildEstimatedDataForKey
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _rebuildAllEstimatedData
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] set
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] unset
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] increment
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] add
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] addUnique
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] remove
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] op
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] clear
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _getSaveJSON
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _canBeSerialized
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] fetch
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] save
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] destroy
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] parse
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] clone
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] isNew
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] change
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] existed
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] hasChanged
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] changedAttributes
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] previous
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] previousAttributes
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] isValid
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] validate
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] _validate
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] getACL
I2014-05-22T20:36:17.590Z] setACL
```

Comment: You don't need a `for-in` statement to get only one property. Just use `object.maxPrice`

Comment: ...oh wait, you don't know the name of the property? You'll need to show what the data structure looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `results` is an array of objects, but those objects are not the type you're expecting (perhaps an internal structure from Parse). From a quick look at the Parse docs, my guess is that you need to do something like:

```
results[i].get("fieldName")
```

to access the values of the returned object. And that means you'd need to know the field names you want to access ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use the toJSON() method on a parse object to retrieve the json object of your data.

```
results[i].toJSON();
```